# Get indexPath from UICollectionViewController to UICollectionViewCell subclass

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionviewcell

in my view controller I Am loading a custom CollectionViewCell with subclass. Based on the position of a cell's indexpath I want to format the text labels differently. I.e. first row has only one cell with bigger text, whereas the second has two cell with smaller text.

How can I access the indexpath from my UICollectionView in my UICollectionViewCell subclass? I tried a delegate protocol but this always returns nil.

Code below and Thanks so much!

Markus

UICollectionViewController:

```
import UIKit

protocol WorkoutDataViewControllerCVDataSource: AnyObject {

func workoutType(for workoutDataViewControllerCV: WorkoutDataViewControllerCV) -> WorkoutType
func workoutDistance(for workoutDataViewControllerCV: WorkoutDataViewControllerCV) -> Double
func workoutDuration(for workoutDataViewControllerCV: WorkoutDataViewControllerCV) -> Double
func workoutInstantVelocity(for workoutDataViewControllerCV: WorkoutDataViewControllerCV) -> Double
}

final class WorkoutDataViewControllerCV: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!

weak var dataSource: WorkoutDataViewControllerCVDataSource!

private lazy var velocityFormatter = VelocityFormatter(dataSource: self, delegate: self)
private lazy var averageVelocityFormatter = VelocityFormatter(dataSource: self, delegate: self)

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.collectionView.register(MeasurementCollectionViewCell.preferredNib, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: MeasurementCollectionViewCell.preferredReuseIdentifier)
}

 }

   // MARK: - Managing UICollectionView

 extension WorkoutDataViewControllerCV: UICollectionViewDataSource {

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 4
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Measurement Cell", for: indexPath)
    return cell
     }

    }

   extension WorkoutDataViewControllerCV: UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                    layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
                    sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

    let availableWidth = self.view.frame.width

    switch indexPath.row {
    case 0: return CGSize(width: availableWidth, height: 150)
    case 1: return CGSize(width: availableWidth/2.1, height: 150)
    case 2: return CGSize(width: availableWidth/2.1, height: 150)
    case 3: return CGSize(width: availableWidth, height: 150)
    default:
        return CGSize(width: availableWidth/2.1, height: 150)
    }
}
}

   // MARK: - Managing VelocityFormatter

   extension WorkoutDataViewControllerCV: VelocityFormatterDataSource     {

func duration(for velocityFormatter: VelocityFormatter) -> Double {
    return dataSource.workoutDuration(for: self)
}

func distance(for velocityFormatter: VelocityFormatter) -> Double {
    return dataSource.workoutDistance(for: self)
}

func instantVelocity(for velocityFormatter: VelocityFormatter) -> Double {
    return dataSource.workoutInstantVelocity(for: self)
}
}
```

**UICollectionViewCell.swift**

```
    import UIKit

  final class MeasurementCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

@IBOutlet private var measurementPropertyLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet private var measurementValueLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet private var measurementUnitLabel: UILabel!

static let preferredReuseIdentifier = "Measurement Cell"
static let preferredNib = UINib(nibName: "MeasurementCollectionViewCell", bundle: nil)

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    updateMeasurement(property: "Speed", value: "100", unit: "km/h")

    //measurementValueLabel.font = measurementValueLabel.font.monospacedDigitFont
}

func updateMeasurement(property: String, value: String, unit: String?) {
    measurementPropertyLabel.text = property
    measurementValueLabel.text = value
    measurementUnitLabel.text = unit
       }

    }
```

Comment: Why do you need the index path inside the cell class? The logic for deciding whether a cell should use different formatting or not should not be the decision of the cell. It should be the decision of the view controller.

Comment: @rmaddy you are right...I guess my first thought was that this class "controls" the xib for the cell and since the xib is a view it would be the right approach. But the cell is ultimately delivered by the view controller, so I'll put the formatting there. Thanks!

Comment: The formatting still goes in the cell but the view controller should tell the cell what state it is in so the cell can draw itself appropriately.

Comment: @rmaddy thanks! But I am confused a bit. How would you control the layout? in cellforitem? and then load a different xib and class? Sorry, I am noob to this stuff.

Answer (score 2):

Get the instance of cell in `UICollectionView delegate` method `collectionView(_, didSelectItemAt _)`.

```
extension WorkoutDataViewControllerCV: UICollectionViewDelegate {

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        if let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as? MeasurementCollectionViewCell {
            cell.selectedIndexPath(indexPath)
        }
    }
}
```

The `indexPath` will be passed as an argument in method `selectedIndexPath` to `MeasurementCollectionViewCell` from above method.

```
class MeasurementCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    ......
    func selectedIndexPath(_ indexPath: IndexPath) {

        //Do your business here.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the responder chain to get the collection view of a cell with which you can get the index path. Just add these extensions in a new file called `UICollectionViewCell+IndexPath.swift`.

```
extension UIResponder {
    func next<T: UIResponder>(_ type: T.Type) -> T? {
        return next as? T ?? next?.next(type)
    }
}

extension UICollectionViewCell {
    var indexPath: IndexPath? {
        return next(UICollectionView.self)?.indexPath(for: self)
    }
}
```

Now inside your cell, you can use `self.indexPath`

Answer (score 1):

Pretty straight forward way would be storing the `indexPath` into the subclass of `UICollectionViewCell` class. Assign it while returning from `cellForRow at: index path`. So now the subclassed collectionviewcell has access to the indexpath of it's own

Comment: Don't do this. A cell should never know its index path. It can be wrong as cells are inserted, removed, or reordered.

Comment: Can you please explain what can go wrong in case of 1. inserting, 2. deleting, 3. reordered.

Comment: The index path you gave to a cell could be wrong after such actions. This is why a cell doesn’t have an index path. A cell should never need to know its index path for any reason.

Comment: Yes i got you point, in case OP managed to update the `indexPath` while these scenario comes, wouldn't be okay ?

Comment: But why? Why force knowledge where it doesn't belong? You can make it work with extra effort but the point is that you should try to make it work because it's the wrong solution.

Comment: My point is, no solution isn't wrong until you have control over it and that works. It just another way to put it in work, this way may have some pros & cons, its the trade off the OP makes, but the solution isn't wrong until it works.